# Slideshow crashes FF

Tags: firefox, slideshow

I have a slideshow working perfectly on every browser except FF.  I know the slideshow is the problem because it is only on the homepage and every other page loads fine, but I can't figure out what's wrong.  I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRqSf/) and put the exact same code, and all I can see is that FF is a bit slower but that's it.  The actual homepage crashes or, at the very best, the slides move at about 1 cm per second.

Can someone take a look at the code?  I know I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's the actual [link](http://bellotaestudio.com/cmtd/)

Comment: If it doesn't crash in the jsFiddle, could you link to your actual page? (Also, a little syntax error in there; [here's that fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/pRqSf/1/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I didn't change anything but it is working now, so problem solved.